# Connecting to GCE instance using service account and IAP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, terraform-provider-gcp, google-iap

This is apparently an easy task but for some reason I cannot accomplish. In a (terraform local-exec) pipeline (thus, non-interactively), I need to login to a given GCE instance authenticating by a specific service account I've the credentials json file for, using IAP proxy.

In other words, I need to upgrade the following command:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone "europe-west1-d" "<instance name>" --project "<prj-id>" --tunnel-through-iap --command "echo 'Hello World'"
```

I was wondering if there's a command to perform that and if i need a particular set of IAMs bound to the SA to allow that.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of search and investigation, it seems there's no way for a service account to login using IAP to compute engine.

Basically, the needed grant simply cannot be assigned to a service account at all.

A SA *can* ssh into a computer instance, though, assuming a valid key was shared between the parts (a key can be generated when the compute engine instance is provisioned). This makes the process not so pratical in everyday use, but theoretically possible.

Comment: Try adding the [--impersonate-service-account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--impersonate-service-account) flag to the command line. That is a supported option for the `gcloud compute ssh` command.

Comment: Tnx @JohnHanley. Generally speaking it works, but it turned out that you cannot grant the IAM for starting a IAP tunnel to a service account. So, you can execute gcloud impersonating a SA, but the latter cannot start a IAP tunnel

Comment: This page lists the permissions required to use a service account: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding

Comment: Tnx @JohnHanley I see. That reference is totally useful! Nonetheless if you try to add iap.tunnelInstances.accessViaIAP to a SA you get this error: "Cannot assign IAM to this resource". This seems to contradict the document you linked (or maybe the error is elsewhere?)

Comment: I think the riddle is that you _as user_ must have the _iap.tunnelInstances.accessViaIAP_ and then _actAs_ a given SA. But you _cannot_ assign and login as SA in a first place.

Comment: That permission is supported for a project's IAM policy binding and not a service account's.